# DPDT switch to control DPDT relay

Tags: relay, motor-controller, polarity, toggle-switch, dpdt

this is a bit of a long shot but here goes.

I need to buy a speed controller for an electric ride on car and I've had no success in finding one with a reverse polarity switch and one that also accepts a hall sensor as a throttle, they all come with potentiometers which are useless to me.

So, I know i can use a DPDT relay or a switch to change polarity but as there'll be currents in excess of 20a going through the relay at times, i don't want that relay near my son's gear shift, in case it fails under load.

My thinking is to have the motor connected to the relay/switch to take the brunt of the current and control the relay/switch with the gear shift that is a DPDT on,off,on switch. Is this possible?
I just can't figure out how I would wire up the switch to the motor connected relay/switch to control it...any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using electromagnetic relay now a days ??  Use solid state relay.

Comment: Use digital devices.

Comment: that doesn't help me understand what i'm trying to do

Comment: I would be concerned about maximum accel and decel rates as well as the possibility of changing motor direction at speed. Standard approach would be to use an electronic speed control (ESC). Find one with a datasheet that shows one end of the speed potentiometer connected to ground and you should be able to use the Hall sensor.

Comment: trust me, i've tried for hours trying to get my hall sensor to work with an ESC but as it's looking for 0-5v and the hall sensor is 1-4v, I can't get the motor speed to 0 or 100, so it's not an option for me. 
i've tried upping the voltage to the hall sensor which does help in getting the 5v i need at the top but then it makes the bottom even worse. I've tried with resistors and still doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

i think i've found the answer. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IP2jR1Pct4k
using 2 SPDT Relays and my gear shift switch.